# Graphical solution (with two variables), solution properties.

Tags: optimization

[image]

(c) infeasibility depends on the constraints; if we look at the graph we can see that (1, 1) is the intersection of constraint (I) and (II), and for this to be infeasible we need **t** in constraint (III) to $t>3$, because then if you won't find a point that satisfies all the constraints.

now the other three I'm not so sure, I know how to think about it graphically but I don't know how to do that algebraically. **One optimal solution**: if there is only one optimal solution that exists in a corner point of the feasible region. **infinitely many optimal solutions**: when the points lie on a line. **unbounded**: an open feasible region. I want to solve a, b, d algebraically.

Comment: A formal hint: $x_1, x_2 \leq 0$ is not a  non-negativity condition. It has to be $x_1, x_2 \geq 0$. And your solution for a) is right.

Comment: I fixed it now =P

Comment: a) is right? what do you mean by that? **(Oh, maybe you meant (c) )**

Comment: I thought, that you commented a). If $t=3$, then all three constraints intersect at $(x_1,x_2)=(1,1)$. You can insert the values in the third constraint and calculate the value of t: $t \cdot 1+1= 4$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some hints:

**a)** If the slope of the third constraint not equal to the slope of the objective function and the slope varies between 3 and $-\frac{1}{2}$ then you have one optimal solution. Therefore $-\frac{1}{2} < t \leq 3$ and $t \neq 1$. If $t \leq -\frac{1}{2}$, then the third constraint is steeper (or equal slope) than the second constraint and the linear program becomes unbounded.

**b)** You have infinitely many solution if the line of the objective function can be (parallel) shifted onto a line of a constraint. That one line of a constraint has to have the same slope as the objective function. The objective function is $z=x_1+x_2$. Solving for $x_2$ gives $x_2=z-x_1$. Therefore the slope is $-1$. The third constraint has to have the same slope.

**c)** If you have no solution space, then the LP is not feasible. 
Therefore the slope has to be so small, that the third constraint line    doesn´t intersect (1/1) any more. Thus the slope has to be greater than 3.
The current solution space (without the third constraint) is the pink area.

**d)** t has to be smaller or equal $-\frac{1}{2}$. In this case the third constraint is steeper ( or parallel) than (to) the red line.

In general you should take a pencil, a ruler and a rubber and draw the third constraint for some values of t. For each value of t a new solution space has to be determined. Especially take care of the inequality signs.

Comment: from **b)** we get that $t=1$, and when $t=1$ we have infinitely many solutions, therefore in **a)** to get one optimal solution we know that **t** is NOT equal to 1, and like you said in the comments we can insert $(x_1, x_2)=(1,1)$ into the third constraint to get $t=3$, so we know that $1<t<=3$ and of course $t<1$ and now I'm going to try to figure out if **t** is greater than (or equal) to something when it's smaller than 1.

Comment: so, we already figured out that $1<t<=3$ and just now I got the following as well, $3<t<1$, by building a matrix out of constraint $(II)$ and $(III)$ and I just left the **t** as the first element in the second row and solved it by making the result (of either row) less than 1, i.e. $result<1$. Thank you so very much, *I think* that answered all of my questions, otherwise I'll be back =P

Comment: OH! and regarding **c)** and **d)**, since $t=1$ gives **infinitely many solutions**, and $-3<t<1$  and  $1<t<=3$ give **only one optimal solutions**, we know that we have **no solution** when $3>t$ and **unbounded** when $t<=-3$